# How to set row color dynamically on jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, css

I would like to set a row color like following:

```
<tr style="background-color:#c55186">
```

But for some reason the style attribute do not overwrite tablesorters css.

It is not enough to use css odd and even. The coloring does not follow any pattern.

Fiddle test page:

http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4770/

Comment: Do you want that to happen when it's clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `background #fff` from CSS is used, because white TD is above purple TR.

You can overwrite white background by transparent for table rows which have `style` attribute using

```
.tablesorter tr[style] td {background: transparent}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/4774/

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `theme.blue.css` contains

```css
.tablesorter-blue td {
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Therefore, you don't see row's background because cell's background hide it.

Then, you can use, for example,

```html
<tr class="customBackground">
```

```css
.customBackground > td {
    background-color: #c55186;
}
```